# Request to webapi get method with parameters returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I get a 404 error when calling this method on my WebApi.

On my ApiController I have a ArchiveTradingConfiguration method.

```
public class TradingConfigurationController : ApiController
{
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public bool ArchiveTradingConfiguration(string correlationId, string symbol)
    {
...
    }
}
```

Here is my startup.cs

```
public static class Startup
{
 public static void ConfigureApp(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiWithAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
        defaults: null
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ArchiveTradingConfiguration",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{correlationId}/{symbol}"
        );
     }
}
```

When I make the request i use:

```
var correlationId  = "SomeGuidAsString";
var symbol = "SomeStringValue"
var url = "api/TradingConfiguration/ArchiveTradingConfiguration/" + correlationId + "/" + symbol;
```

e.g. 
  http://localhost:8421/api/TradingConfiguration/ArchiveTradingConfiguration/034f7d92-dd02-46b3-9db2-11990ea5860c/SomeStringValue

Any idea?

Comment: can u please test ur app without  another rule , remove first and second config and test .

Comment: I still get 404 if i remove the other rules

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. I made 2 changes. I dont know if the first was needed. The second was for sure.

My Action contained the name of my controller. Changed the name of the action to Archive

I my route config I had forgot to add /{action}/

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{correlationId}/{symbol}"
```